# Which or That? which one to use before "oranges"?

Tags: relative-clauses

Sentence: Here are oranges_____have been grown in South Africa.

Question: "which" or "that" or "both" would be correct to fill in the blanks of the above sentence?

Comment: Both are grammatically OK, but "that" is preferable in AmE.

Comment: In AmE, IMHO, *both* are equally used  NGRAm indicates *which* has become less popular over the last two hundred years (entire corpus, not just AmE), and *that* appears virtually unchanged. Seer https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=which+have+been%2Cthat+have+been&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 Note crossover ca 1980!